# How does the pandas vectorized concept ensure samr row is worked upon when RHS uses filter?

Tags: python, pandas

Vectorized approach is said to he the fastest.

In the below example, the value `1` is set into all cells of `newcol` where `col` value is greater than 50.

```
df.loc[df.loc['col'>50],'newcol']=1
```

The below code has a non-constant right-hand side. Where type is `c1`, it is summing up the value of the `w1` and `w2` columns. How does this work internally - for example, is this row by row and how does it ensure that the same row is summed and set in the Result column?

```
df.loc[df.type=='c1',['Result']]=df.loc[df.type=='c1',['w1']]+df.loc[df.type=='c1',['w2']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does the pandas vectorized concept ensure samr row is worked upon when RHS uses filter?

Because there is same condition, here:

```
df.type=='c1'
```

So filtering only rows if `True`s in mask for `w1` and `w2`, summed and assigned to rows only matched by mask in right side:

```
df.loc[df.type=='c1','Result']=df.loc[df.type=='c1','w1']+df.loc[df.type=='c1','w2']

#fr avoid 3 times same condition is used variable m
m = df.type=='c1'
df.loc[m,'Result']=df.loc[m,'w1']+df.loc[m,'w2']
```

Comment: Ok so if the lhs and rhs counts do not match then it will throw error?

Comment: @variable - Do you think `df.loc[df.type=='c1','w1']+df.loc[df.type=='c2','w2']` ?

Comment: I am asking what happens if the lhs of equal to sign. And rhs of equal to sign have different row counts.

Comment: @variable - `what happens if the lhs of equal to sign` If think `df.type=='c1'` it compare column `type` by scalar `c1` for equal and ouput is `boolean Series`  filled by `True`s if match and `False` if no match

Comment: Ok so it work purely on basis of boolean concept. Ok thanks.